# In the explanation of fitgeometry=general of drizzlepac.tweakreg.TweakReg, How are there two different rotation with respect to "x axis" and "y axis"?

Tags: observational-astronomy, drizzle, tweakreg

```
While the shift file looks nearly identical to the prior run, 
this is because the axis-dependent rotation 
and scale values are averaged together in the shiftfile. 
To determine the actual values, it is necessary to inspect the logfile.

j9irw5kaq  SCALE_X: 1.000008792  SCALE_Y: 1.00000757  ROT_X: 0.002818152  ROT_Y: 359.998708  SKEW: 359.9958898
j9irw4b1q  SCALE_X: 0.999986877  SCALE_Y: 1.00003072  ROT_X: 0.004877188  ROT_Y: 0.00405990  SKEW:  -0.0008173
```

The above script is related to the axis explanation of fitgeometry=general of drizzlepac.tweakreg.TweakReg.
(and this is from [DrizzlePac tutorial](https://github.com/spacetelescope/notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/DrizzlePac/align_multiple_visits/align_multiple_visits.ipynb))

How are there two different rotation with respect to "x axis" and "y axis"?

In two-dimensional space, there is just one rotation with x-axis and y-axis separately, NOT two rotations.

Comment: Screenshots of text are strongly discouraged in Stack Exchange, especially when you can just copy/paste the actual text. If you add four spaces in the beginning of the line your code-like items will display as a code block (equal spaced font) `like this`. *Thanks!*

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. The ROT_X and ROT_Y values differ by less than the errors, and so are not actually different; 2. A real difference could be an indication of a *distortion*, which cannot be accurately represented by a uniform rotation.

Comment: @ago Thank you for good comment. I edited it.

Comment: @PeterErwin Thank you, but what's the meaning of uniform rotation of "possibilities 2"? Can we rotate the x-axis and y-axis separately?